# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present - asp.net core web api targeting .net framework 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.5, http-status-code-502

I have a server side RESTful API that was created in c# targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 and the CORS configuration i have does not appear to be working...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder => {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowCredentials();
                    });
        });

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddOptions();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        var options = new JwtBearerOptions {
            Audience = "MyAudience"
            Authority = "MyAuthority"
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Each time i make a call to the below API in my controller

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public Task<JsonResult> Get() {

ICollection<string> abc;
try {
    abc = new List<string>(){"A", "B", "C"};
} catch (Exception) {
    abc = null;
}
return Json(abc);
}
```

I get the following error...

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load x Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'x' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502."

The http request from my client has an "Authorization" header in it which is why a preflight response is triggered, it has a valid token etc... so it has nothing to do with this part.

In fact if I create the exact same RESTful API targeting .NET Core 1.0, it works as expected. This leads me to believe there is either an issue with CORS and targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 or there is now some explicit logic i have to add that is otherwise handled implicitly by .NET Core 1.0.

My understanding is that the CORS middleware should be handling all this, does anyone know what the issue might be here?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that this works fine running as localhost, i only see this issue after deploying. Also, i tested this targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 and the issue remained.

Comment: I *may* have run into this same issue.  CORS doesn't allow you to specify credentials when the origin is "any".  To use credentials with CORS, you have to identify specific allowed origins.  I'm unsure if this is your issue, though.  I'm using .Net 4.6.2 with CORS.

Comment: For more info on that point, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):  "When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard."

Comment: @Amy I have checked the response headers and they are exactly what they need to be which makes me believe the CORS middleware is doing its job perhaps in part, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true and Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://something:portnum. I forgot to mention this works fine running on localhost but when it is deployed i see the error. I also tried upgrading to target .NET Framework 4.6.2 but i see the same issue.

Comment: Hm, well if it runs fine on localhost but not after deployment, that *suggests* a configuration issue in the deployed environment rather than an issue with the code itself.  My CORS code is different from yours, but I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Amy I found the issue but i really can't explain what was happening under the hood.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  What a bizarre situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2017.md#aspnet-core-known-issues

Different versions of visual studio 2017 were being used and some projects\dependencies were targeting .Net Core 1.0 and others were targeting .Net Core 1.1 which caused different runtimes to be needed.

Once we sync'd to the newest version of VS2017 (15.2.26430.13), targeted .Net Core 1.1 and installed the new runtime on the server the issue went away.

The CORS error above was actaully a side effect of a 502 (Bad Request) error that i was missing in the callstack...